# book about a man who built a device that could influence people

Tags: story-identification

A man lived an a city and built a device that would project an invisible beam, people caught in the beam exhibited strange behavior (perhaps violence or mind control, I cannot remember). He was starting to think how  he is going to rule the world, but he was found out. Someone drew lines on a map of streets where people went bonkers and lines intersected on this man's building.

I think the book was written before 1990.

Comment: It may not be an exact match, but I thought I'd mention Frank Herbert's short story "Operation Syndrome": People randomly go insane in multiple cities; protagonist find a link between cities with "outbreaks" and the itinerary of a concert featuring a "Musikron" which transmits the music directly into the subconscious - with devastating side effects. Though in that story, the Syndrome was an accident, rather than some nefarious scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about people going insane, it's about an invisible ray that transmutes gold and kills people, but this is very similar to "[The Mystery Metal](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?80715)" (1930) by H. James and Maurice James.  It was published in *Science Wonder Stories*, March 1930.

> "Here," he pointed out, on a map of the city, "is the location of the Interstate Bank and Trust Co. Draw a line through the vaults and the place where Tom was found dead; it runs like this." He made a mark with a ruler. "Then here is the location of the Hollingsworth National. Draw a line straight north — the three men fell dead on the north side, in line with the vault, you know. The two lines intersect at 332 Grosvenor Place."
>
> "It is from there that the fatal rays have been directed! Furthermore," he explained "the fiend must have his instruments on the eighth floor; otherwise it would have affected other persons in the path of the rays. Directed from higher up, they would not have struck the men in front of the Hollingsworth Bank. Directed lower, they would have affected others."

In this story we don't find out the motivation of the scientist, John Kay, who is using the ray, since he is killed by misadventure before the heroes arrive.  You can read the entire story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Science_Wonder_Stories_v01n10_1930-03_bogof39-cape1736/page/n35/mode/1up).

Comment: I think I'm remembering fragments of two stories from the same book, as I clearly remember controlling people as well. The Mystery Metal is definitely one of the stories.